# Vuforia ARcamera Screen position out of view frustum

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, hololens, frustum, arcamera

We are working on a project for the Hololens and for some reason, when running it crashes on the hololens but not in the simulation. We have tried all the simple fixes (rebooting, closing, deleting camera, setting the size) and all have failed. We get the following error:

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\artifacts/generated/Metro/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: 51)

Screen position out of view frustum (screen pos 0.000000, 0.000000, 2000.000000) (Camera rect 0 0 1268 720)

(Filename: C:\buildslave\unity\build\Runtime/Camera/Camera.cpp Line: 2974)

The program '[3704] TextBoxTest.exe' has exited with code -2147483645 (0x80000003).

We are building a simple and small project with vuforia to recognize QR-Codes and place a cube right on top of them. This works for the simulation as it should but crashes straight away on the Hololens.

Any tips? What does this error mean? We have wasted a whole day on this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Changing the eyewear setting in the Vuforia configuration fixed my issue. 
[image]

Comment: Thank you! Fixed this horribly annoying bug for me.